# Amazon Web Services GPU G2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gpu

Today I got setup with AWS GPU G2 instance (g2.2xlarge). I wanted to test out the 3d hardware capability that is offered as mentioned here

> http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/
>
> Features:
>
> High Frequency Intel Xeon E5-2670 (Sandy Bridge) Processors
>   High-performance NVIDIA GPU with 1,536 CUDA cores and 4GB of video
>   memory On-board hardware video encoder designed to support up to eight
>   real-time HD video streams (720p@30fps) or up to four real-time FHD
>   video streams (1080p at 30 fps). Support for low-latency frame capture
>   and encoding for either the full operating system or select render
>   targets, enabling high-quality interactive streaming experiences.

But when I tried running 3dmark 2011 to try things out. I got an exception "No DXGI adapters found"
Also I noticed, dxdiag says no hardware acceleration available.

So im a bit puzzled as to why I dont see the NVIDIA GPU with 1500+ cuda cores.

Also, It would be great if Azure offered 3d compute capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, there is some setup required before GPU can be used. One needs to install nvidia grid k520 driver as well as the latest cuda toolkit. Finally install vnc server on the instance and then open relevant ports in the aws instance. Then install vnc client on your local pc and that should give you access to the gpu.

Thanks